# Transition a single div for only one time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a vertical category like https://www.amazon.in . I have made the vertical menu and it is working with the transition. But the problem is, I want to make the transition for only one time when the category is clicked. Then all the elements of the category will open without any transition.

```css
#header .header_section .header_content .header_right_part .search_bar_part .category_part .category_main_box .category_info_part {
    /* width: 75%; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(246, 212, 160, .9);
    /* transform: translateX(-100%); */
    /* opacity: 0; */
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;

}


 #header .header_section .header_content .header_right_part .search_bar_part .category_part .category_main_box .category_left_list > ul > li:hover .category_info_part{
    display: block;
    /* transform: translateX(0%); */
    /* opacity: 1; */
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 863px;
}
```

The transition is working on all the elements of the menu. But I only want to make the transition for the first time, Then there will be no transition. How can it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try `animation-iteration-count: 1`

Comment: yes, I have tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JavaScript, you can use it to add and remove classes from certain elements (instructions [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_class.asp)).

What I would do is place the transition info in a specific class :

```
.transitionOn {
  /* include everything that should only be there when you want the transition */
}
```

That way, you can add an [onclick event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) to remove the transitionOn class from what you no longer want to have a transition. I'm not sure if the transition will complete in this case, so I would add a [timeout](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to make sure the class isn't removed before the transition occurs.